# Parse Migration - Missed Finalize

Tags: parse-platform

I have completed the parse migration completely including the data and files. The clients are also pointing to the  standalone parse server.

I have missed to finalize the migration in parse dashboard and now it is showing me the migrate button again. Will this create a problem when parse hosting shuts down? Do I need to migrate the data again and finalize it?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. You don't need to worry as you can try again but you will first need to clean up your target database as Parse's migration tool will only migrate data to an empty database.